# Easiest web development method from Java perspective?

Tags: java, html, web

I have always been a front-end Java programmer, sometimes had to do C# on .NET but for the most part, Java is probably all I know about.

Just currently I have to do a small-scale website doing extremely simple thing and I really don't know where to start. My HTML skill is probably as good as I am with XML on Android, which is fair to say far less complicated than the HTML source code modern website have. I have almost no experience with PHP either, and no strong background on building or managing a database.

Is there some sort of technology that builds fully working website using mainly Java? It may have other languages I have to familiarize with but for the most part, I'd like to have little learning curve. For the backend I'm very sure I'm going to use cloud server services like Azure or Parse.

This is a very special project of me so I can't let anyone code it rather than me and myself only. Thank you and have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Use Servlets and JSPs for web development it's a start point and then java webservices as you already know XML.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to build all your front-end using the following set of technologies: HTML5, AngularJS, JQuery, javascript, bootstrap. Your backend could exchange json with the front-end. The Bootstrap is the base for all your website and you could get a free template from the web itself, which would severely reduce your hard work at web designing. You would need just to adapt the links and calls, and the AngularJS would handle the controller and other stuffs ( have a chance to learn about ). Some JQuery components, or even AngularJS components would enhance your system usability and combined with javascript would bring most of hard work to front-end. I had the chance do start a system from zero and this is what I did, and now I have an AngularJS app working together with java by having java on the backend ( spring, hibernate, etc ) receiving and providing json data. At github you find some angularjs seed examples which you could use in your app and, again, save time and effort.

Comment: Given the fact that I will most definitely use backend services like Azure, may I eliminate some of the technologies you have mentioned? I assume this means Spring and Hibernate, I have no idea about the others.

Comment: yes sure. If your backend is already set, all you need is to build your front-end. And a good tendency is HTML5 with angularjs and/or jquery. This is completely independent from your backend and could be built without having the backend set yet by just using mock data.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies in advance, My answer is a bit broader in scope,

The Best Development Model for developing any website regardless of your language choice in Azure App Service is to take advantage two powerful features  offered by Azure App Service, **the Continuous Deployment feature and Deployment slots**.

1. Start your website on a git repository and you may have node modules or bower packages, but on build your git will crunch it down to a working website with proper gulp files. [Check out this blog to understand the process](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/).
2. Once you have the git repo working for a simple website, your development process becomes much smoother. **You can commit a change and Continuous deployment will automatically start a deployment for you to get your latest bits into your web app.**. [Check this blog for more details on Continuous Deployment.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/)
3. You can use deployment slots to stage your changes and swap to maintain multiple versions of your web app on the cloud to easily build a production level application that has a last known good state. [Check this blog for more details on Deployment slots.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/)

The two features are the most used features while developing, deploying and servicing any project I work and I have found them very useful to understand them and use them in all their glory.

I am not a Java developer, but from the your question I can see you are looking to start on web development, the quick and powerful way (purely subjective here :D) is to use Asp.Net 5 with Angular 2 Beta. [Here is an end to end tutorial on how to setup a development environment](http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/). Asp.Net 5 should be friendly toward Java developers as it is very light weight and simple to use and works great with vscode and visual studio community edition.

Let me know if the long answer helped, if you need a pure java environment that should be possible too :).